# pyTelegramBotAPI на OpenShift

Tags: python, openshift

Написал я недавно бота на python ( pyTelegramBotAPI ) и решил поставить его на хостинг OpenShift

Сообщения бот получаем методом polling. На компьютере скрипт прекрасно функционирует, а после отправки его на OpenShift бот получал одно сообщение и вырубался.

Возможно, не стоило основной код программы отправлять в файл setup.py, который загружается сразу же, но другого способа запустить скрипт я не нашел.

Python 3.5.1

[Исходный код бота](http://pastebin.com/jA8X5VG0)

Собственно выбивает ошибку на строку

```
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/var/lib/openshift/57517dca0c1e660af1000092/app-root/runtime/rep
>   o//setup.py", line 166, in module
>
> bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
>
> File "/var/lib/openshift/57517dca0c1e660af1000092/python/virtenv/venv/
>   lib/python3.3/site-packages/telebot/**init**.py", line 192, in polling
>
> ```
> self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
> ```
>
> File "/var/lib/openshift/57517dca0c1e660af1000092/python/virtenv/venv/
>   lib/python3.3/site-packages/telebot/**init**.py", line 216, in __threaded_pollin
>   g
>
> ```
> self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
> ```
>
> File "/var/lib/openshift/57517dca0c1e660af1000092/python/virtenv/venv/
>   lib/python3.3/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 103, in raise_exceptions
>
> six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1](http://pastebin.com/jA8X5VG0), self.exc_info[2])
>
> File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/six.py", l
>   ine 329, in reraise
>
> ```
> raise value
> ```
>
> File "/var/lib/openshift/57517dca0c1e660af1000092/python/virtenv/venv/
>   lib/python3.3/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 54, in run
>   remote:     task(*args, **kwargs)

и на эту функцию

```
def log(message):
print("\n~~~~~~")
print(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
print("Message from {0} {1}. (id = {2}, chat = {3}) \n Text - {4}".format(message.from_user.first_name,
                                                                          message.from_user.last_name,
                                                                          str(message.from_user.id),
                                                                          str(message.chat.id),
                                                                          message.text))
```

> functions.log(message)
>     File "/var/lib/openshift/57517dca0c1e660af1000092/app-root/runtime/repo/functions.py", line 16, in log
>
> ```
> message.text))
> ```
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 77-82: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: не могли бы вы ключевые моменты перенести в сам вопрос?

Comment: К слову, вместо str от аргумента функции можно просто написать `{2!s}`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: А ещё в коде отсутствует hashbang, который помог бы быстро понять, какая версия питона используется.

Comment: по последней ошибке print идет в консоль, проверьте кодировку системы на сервере и поддержку юникода.

Answer (score 1):

Первая ошибка была связана с устаревшей версией библиотеки request

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade urllib3 requests
```

исправляет всё.

Проблема с функцией log была из-за неправильного запуска. Я по ошибке запускал через python 2.